# How to use command-line argument files for javac on windows?

Tags: powershell, command-line-arguments, javac

Here's my working directory:

```
C:\GitHub\
```

And under this directory I have:

```
class\ src\ cmain
```

and `cmain` is my argument file.

All my .java source code files are under`src\`

```
main.java CalcHandler.java
```

And here's the content of`cmain`

```
-cp .\class\
-sourcepath .\src\
-d .\class\
.\src\main.java
```

But when I tried compiling `src\main.java` in PowerShell using`cmain`, it is not recognized:

```
PS C:\GitHub> javac @cmain
Usage: javac <options> <source files>                                                                                   
where possible options include:                                                                                           
-g                         Generate all debugging info                                                                  
-g:none                    Generate no debugging info
....
```

I tried this in Linux and it worked fine, contents were exactly the same.

What should I do to make it work?

**Edit**: Apparently this is PowerShell's fault, it worked in command-prompt. But still I'd like to hear from you about how to make it correct in PowerShell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
javac '@cmain'
```

PowerShell parses arguments to commands, and `@cmain` means taking the array `$cmain` and expanding it to one argument per item (splatting). By passing an explicit string you can bypass that automatism.

Other options:

```
javac --% @cmain
```

This will tell PowerShell to stop parsing arguments after the `--%` marker and just pass them verbatim to the other program.

```
javac `@cmain
```

This will escape the `@` so its special behavior will not apply.

Always remember that shell features will need workarounds if you want to pass that syntax to other programs. That's no different than `%` expanding environment variables in `cmd`, or most shells tokenizing arguments at spaces and other whitespace. A small utility program that just prints its arguments can come in handy for diagnosing such cases.